# Vite build into output directory

Tags: vite

i have project structure and when i run npm run build

```
my-app/
├─ node_modules/
├─ dist/
│  ├─ files
│  │   ├─ 1.html
│  │   ├─ 2.html
│  │   ├─ 3.html
│  │   ├─ 4.html
├─ files
│  ├─ 1.html
│  ├─ 2.html
│  ├─ 3.html
│  ├─ 4.html
├─ index.html
├─ main.js
├─ style.scss
├─ package.json
├─ vite.config.js
```

i need like this

```
├─ dist
│  ├─ 1.html
│  ├─ 2.html
│  ├─ 3.html
│  ├─ 4.html
```

Now how can I fix this? Any suggestion?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the docs Guide > [*Static Asset Handling*](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory):

> #### The `public` Directory
>
> [..]
> Then you can place the asset in a special `public` directory under your project root. Assets in this directory will be served at root path `/` during dev, and **copied to the root of the `dist` directory as-is**.

I highlighted your desired effect  in bold.

#### Put static files in `public` folder

Instead of putting your static files in a `files` folder, put them directly into a `public` folder within your sources root. Then the build will move them to the root of `dist` as below:

```
my-app/
├─ dist/
│   ├─ 1.html
│   ├─ 2.html
│   ├─ 3.html
│   ├─ 4.html
├─ public
│  ├─ 1.html
│  ├─ 2.html
│  ├─ 3.html
│  ├─ 4.html
```